# How to switch to py27 environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have successfully installed the python 3.5 and anaconda 4.0. Then I have successfully created a python 2.7 environment in the anaconda prompt by typing the following command:

```
conda install -n py27 python=2.7
```

but when i ty to activate this older version of Python I get this error message:

```
CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find the environment: C:\Users\me\Anaconda3

Wasn't expected =CONDA_PATH_PLACEHOLDER%"
```

When I list all the discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`

I get this message:

```
gl-env  C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env
py      C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\py
py27    C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\py27
untitled C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\untitled
root * C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\
```

I understand that I'm in the root (py35) but how can I switch to py27 with other command than

```
activate py27
```

Answer (score 4):

1- Creating a python2 environment:
`conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda`

2- Activating the new environment like this
`source activate python2`